# How to access parent view controller from popover in swift, using storyboard

Tags: swift, uitableview, interface-builder, popover

Pushing a UIButton in a UIViewController (detailview of a splitviewcontroller) opens a UITableViewController, presented as a popover. This is accomplished by a segue, and "kind" is set as "Present as Popover" in attributes inspector. When a UITableViewCell in the UITableViewController is selected, I want the UIViewController to catch this selection.

This is what I am trying to do in the UITableViewController:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let myViewController = presentingViewController as! MyViewController

        myViewController.variable = cell.someProperty
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This gives in the log: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", indicating that I fail to catch the parentview/presentingview. After reading about popovers, I feel I should implement a delegate and delegate methods somwhere. But I fail to undersetand how.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: just do as This,,, MYViewController.Variable = cell.someProperty..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the delegation design pattern. If I understand your situation correctly, you can accomplish that by doing something like:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // ...

    weak var myViewControllerDelegate: MyViewController? // Make sure it's weak! .. or you know what you're doing, haha

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // ...
        let property = 5 // cell.property
        self.myViewControllerDelegate?.myTableViewController(self, didSelectCellWithProperty: property)
    }
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...

    // In viewDidLoad or elsewhere, if necessary
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //...

        myTableVCInstance.myViewControllerDelegate = self // This will set the delegate we created to self
    }

    func myTableViewController(viewController: MyTableViewController, didSelectCellWithProperty property: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note the naming of `myViewControllerDelegate` so as not to clash with the `delegate` that UITableViewController already has, which would be of type UITableControllerDelegate.

This example is intended to show a point. You would probably want to use a protocol to clean it up.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a very good substitute for using NSNotification, and might solve a lot of troubles I have. However, I am not able to cath the property.  Adding "print (property)" print("Hi") inside  func myTableViewController(viewController: MyTableViewController, didSelectCellWithProperty property: Int) {
    // ...
    } does not print anything, like the method never was called.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.. Are you trying to send a property of the cell to MyViewController?

Comment: Yes, or any property from the tableviewcontroller at all.

Comment: If you pass that property as an argument to the delegate it should work. Maybe you forgot to set MyViewController as the delegate? What happens if you put a breakpoint in the delegate method?

Comment: Adding a breakpoint didn't change anything, meaning the delegate method is never called. Good point :-). I have not set any delegate other than inside the tableviewcontroller in interfcaebuilder. Do the ViewController need to conform to any protocol or delegate methods other than the one you wrote? How would I set the ViewController as delegate?

Comment: After fooling around, its clear that a delegate is missing. But I am absolutely failing to find a way to set the MyViewController as delegate. If I include the UITableViewDelegate to MyViewController class, and in MyTableViewController sets tableview.delegate = myViewControllerDelegate, the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method stops working. I also tried to construct a new project from scratch, with still the same result.

Comment: See my edit above. You need to set the specific delegate property that you created. You cold name this .delegate if you'd like, I just thought this would be clearer for the example. ALSO, keep in mind you're setting the delegate of the viewController, not the tableView

Comment: I really appriciate your effort to help a pain in the neck like me, but still,  "func myTableViewController(viewController: MyTableViewController, didSelectCellWithProperty..." is not repsonding. Not even in the new clean project.

Comment: Are you setting the delegate on the right instance? How are you creating the popover: interface builder, programmatically?

Comment: Yes. I have done it excactly as you suggested. The popover is made in interface builder from the MyViewController to the MyTableViewController. A segue is set to "popover" in the attributes inspector.